# Date time sorting in react table on particular column (column name transaction date)

Tags: reactjs

I am using react table and wanted to sort date time but its not sorting properly either ascending order or descending order.

column defined code: Using below code to sort the date time.

```
{Header: 'Transaction Date',accessor: 'transationDate', style: {textAlign: "center"},
                          sortMethod: (a, b) => {
                            var a1 = new Date(a).getTime();
                            var b1 = new Date(b).getTime();
                          if(a1<b1)
                          return 1;
                          else if(a1<b1)
                          return -1;
                          else
                          return 0;
                          }
                        },
```

descending order Sorted Result:

[image]

Comment: Your if and else conditions are the same.

Answer (score 5):

I don´t know if anyone still struggles with that but for me 'sortType' did the magic instead of 'sortMethod'.

```
{Header: 'Transaction Date',accessor: 'transationDate', style: {textAlign: "center"},
                      sortType: (a, b) => {
                        var a1 = new Date(a).getTime();
                        var b1 = new Date(b).getTime();
                      if(a1<b1)
                      return 1;
                      else if(a1>b1)
                      return -1;
                      else
                      return 0;
                      }
                    },
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work! Just flip the < with >.

```
{Header: 'Transaction Date',accessor: 'transationDate', style: {textAlign: "center"},
                          sortMethod: (a, b) => {
                            var a1 = new Date(a).getTime();
                            var b1 = new Date(b).getTime();
                          if(a1<b1)
                          return 1;
                          else if(a1>b1)
                          return -1;
                          else
                          return 0;
                          }
                        },
```

Comment: I tried but still its not sorting. Could you please suggest any thing else?